# How can I show Text in multi-colour in Firemonkey

Tags: colors, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

I need to show text in multi-colours, rather like highlighting portions of say xml or json.  A "Richedit" or "Html" component would work.

I cant find any native ones, how can I do it ?

Comment: FireMonkey has a `TWebBrowser` component, so you should be able to use it to show an HTML page. There is no native FireMonkey equivalent of a RichEdit control, but there may be third party components for that.

Comment: TMS has made a 3rd party text control that can show html: TTMSFMXHTMLText. I use it a lot and it works very well.